# \special commands result in Acrobat being unable to display PDF correctly

Tags: errors, miktex, texworks, bookmarks, acrobat

I'm currently using TeXworks 0.4.5 with Windows 7 SP1 and MikTeX 2.9 to compile a thesis template that was constructed by a colleague. ([If you would like to see the template, click here](http://www.ion.le.ac.uk/~rcf11/fear_thesis_latex_template.zip)). This includes `\special` commands, which should mean the resulting PDF generated by LaTeX has the table of contents built into the PDF itself as bookmarks (allowing for easier navigation in PDF readers). One of these commands is given below.

`\special{pdf: out 1 << /Title (\thechapter. Introduction) /Dest [@thispage /FitH @ypos] >>}`

However, when I compile the document, Acrobat says 'An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to correct the problem.' It also refuses to display the page that the bookmark created by `\special` should point to.

I know that it is definitely the `\special` commands causing the issue, since commenting them out fixes the problem.

Does anyone know how to generate a table of contents that is compatible with Acrobat, either by altering the `\special` command or by using some other method to do so?

Comment: Hi and welcome, what exactly is the template link? As far as i can tell by the bit of code found at the linked site, i can only say: Be careful, part of this should not be done.

Comment: using `\special` restricts you to latex (normally) it's usually better to let hyperref deal with this then it will use whatever is required depending if you are using latex or pdflatex, and add it automatically without you requiring to put anything other than the standard `\section{zzz}` markup.

Comment: There is also [bookmark](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) (which uses `hyperref`) or [navigator](http://ctan.org/pkg/navigator).

Comment: @Johannes_B Which part ought not be done?

Comment: @cfr Please look down to the Handy Tips part and especially to *Split figures*. Do you consider this clean coding?

Comment: @Johannes_B Whether it's clean coding or not doesn't change the fact that that is how to do it if you are submitting to the journals in question; clean code is useless if it leads to a journal rejecting your manuscript.

Comment: I edited the original post to point directly to the relevant thesis template, as well as noting that it's definitely the `\special` commands that are causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, all – I will give `hyperref` a go!

Comment: @JohnCoxon Consider it a flag for users coming here via google. If the journal does it that way, it's fine with me.

Comment: @Johannes_B No. But I didn't think it would necessarily be obvious to all users coming here via google. (And I didn't know if the `\special`s were decent coding or not.)

Comment: @cfr It was just a comment. Not to be taken too seriously. But i think, as pointed out before, that `hyperref` will do its job quite good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use package `hyperref` you will get the inbuild bookmarks of `hyperref`.  If you want to configure the bookmarks you can load package `bookmark` **after** `hyperref`.  See `texdoc hyperref` and `texdoc bookmark` for more information or search this side ;-)

Give the following a try:

```
\usepackage[hypcap=true]{hyperref}  % hypcap corrects an error pointing to images 
%\usepackage{bookmark}              % delete leading % if ypou want to try it
```

So each `\chapter` or `\section`or ... will be bookmarked. You do not need further more `\special`.